# HTTP Post gave error if there is 0 input recodes

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to use the HTTP Post if there is a record in the precursor step, but if there are 0 records in precursor step it's giving an error.

```
 HTTP Client New.0 - Error finding field [xxxxx] !
```

Is there any way to handle this error or don't perform the HTTP Post step if a precursor step doesn't have any records.

Comment: I think your error is that the step is not finding the field you've put in the step, rather than no row being fed to it. Screen Shots of the Steps configurations would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the opinion of Cristian Curti that the error does not come from empty stream but a bad configuration of your `POST step`.

However, just in case, you have a `Detect empty stream` step, documented [here](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Detect+empty+stream), with a simple example.